# Looking for a music player that can filter by filename and play webm audio files

Tags: software-recommendation, music, music-player, media-library

I am looking for a music player and organizer for Ubuntu 14.04 that can

- Filter/Search audio files by filename
- Play audio formats like **webm**, ogg

I tried Clementine and Deadbeef but both of them lacked the qualities I mentioned above.

On Windows, I used Foobar which had these features.

Comment: Is any [player of the list we have here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197721/audio-players-that-access-music-library-as-file-browser-and-see-folder-structur) suitable? My favorite still is Guayadeque.

Comment: I tried **Quod Libet** and it fulfills my first requirement i.e. filtering by filenames. @Takkat Can you check whether Guayadeque supports webm audio files ?

Comment: That's a codec rather than a player issue.

Comment: Rhythmbox is playing webm and ogg files and also allows me to search by filename. I don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried it. Maybe it installed some codecs when I tried to force play the webm/ogg file.

Answer (score 0):

While there are some great Linux audio players (and I would encourage you to explore them) there is absolutely nothing to stop you running your old friend Foobar on Ubuntu using Wine. Run the following from a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

And then download and install Foobar:

```
cd $HOME/Desktop
wget https://www.foobar2000.org/files/d392066748f9762853bd06ad67f175fe/foobar2000_v1.3.10.exe
wine foobar2000_v1.3.10.exe
```

And this will be enough to get Foobar running nicely on Ubuntu. Below is a screenshot of Foobar running on Trusty Tahr:

[image]

If you are interested in extending Foobar a little further you could also consider using the same process to install Foobar's [Free Encoder Pack...](http://www.foobar2000.org/encoderpack)